# looped items showing up but cannot grab the id?

Tags: javascript

I have this working example that is showing the id of elements after a forEach has been made but in my case I can see the looped element yet I can get the class List but I cannot get the id for some reason any idea why this is happening ?

[image]

```js
// Test 

let [...items] = document.querySelectorAll('div')

console.log(items, "The items are here ");

items.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.id, "Get the id ");
})


// Real issue 
//items.forEach(item => {
//   console.log(item, 'the item')
//   console.log(item.classList, 'the item with classLid')
//   console.log(item.id, 'the item with id')
//}
//)
```

```html
<div id='1'>A</div>
<div id='2'>B</div>
<div id='3'>C</div>
```

Comment: Where is your JS residing? External sheet or in a script tag in your HTML doc?

Comment: external sheet but using load of modules

Comment: Is it located after your HTML in the body at the end or in the head and if in the head have you defer'd the script tag that links it?

Comment: I see the ids my friend. 

https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/OJmmjBq?editors=1112

So, what exactly is the issue dear

Comment: I had a similar issue once when I was testing some code and created a quick HTML page and forgot to 'defer' the script tag in the head section. Selectors were working on some queries yet not in others. getElementsByClassName would return element classes, yet querySelectorAll returned undefined selectors I knew were present.